# How to install sass (css framework) to mac version 10.6.8

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass

I have tried this

```
$ sudo gem install sass
```

and it gives me an error of

-bash: $: command not found

I have tried a lot of tutorials. I got the video tutorial http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ruby-foundations/introduction/installing-ruby/play and I managed to install sass. but then when I tryed to run sass, it says gem not found (something like that)

I am wondering. Is there a way to do this without using the termianl?

I also installed LifeReload, and with it, sass does work but then when I try to run compass, same errors apear in the terminal

Basically every line I enter in the terminal regarding this process, I get 'command not found'

Normally when I follow tutorials I kind of get what's going on, but with this I am comletely lost, so sorry if I am not explaining it well

Do you know anu easier way to get this working?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to enter the $. The $ stands for your prompt and indicates that the line is to be entered a) in a terminal b) as a normal user (as opposed to root).

Comment: thanks that is great. by the way do you know how I can access a css file sitting on my desktop? I believe terminals default location in at the use directory (right?) so how do I go to use/desktop/somefolder/style.css - thank

Answer (score 3):

Just don't include the dollar sign, it's the prompt:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Documentation usually includes the prompt to make clear you have to enter the text following it in the shell.